# What does "local n=${x##*wlan}" mean?

Tags: bash

I'm looking through a bash script I've inherited and come across this line:

```
local n=${x##*wlan}
```

I've never seen this syntax, I know that `local` means a variable in the scope of a function, I'm just unsure about the `${*##}` part and it's pretty tricky to google that syntax.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It removes everything up to the last `wlan` match in the `$x` variable.

```
asldkjflkasjdfljsdwlanalsdkjfkajsdflswlanasdlfaksdlfj
#                 ^^^^               ^^^^
#                     |                  |--->
#                     |                  ${x##*wlan}
#                     ${x#*wlan}
```

See an example:

```
$ x="hello1hello2hello3"

$ echo "${x##*hello}"  # with two ## it matches the longest matching pattern
3

$ echo "${x#*hello}"   # with one # it matches the shortest matching pattern
1hello2hello3
```

Graphically:

```
hello1hello2hello3
#                ^
#    ^           ${x##*hello}
#    ${x#*hello}
```

From [Bash Reference Manual - 3.5.3 Shell Parameter Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

> **${parameter##word}**
>
> The word is expanded to produce a pattern just as in filename
>   expansion (see Filename Expansion). If the pattern matches the
>   beginning of the expanded value of parameter, then the result of the
>   expansion is the expanded value of parameter with the shortest
>   matching pattern (the ‘#’ case) or the longest matching pattern (the
>   ‘##’ case) deleted. If parameter is ‘@’ or ‘*’, the pattern removal
>   operation is applied to each positional parameter in turn, and the
>   expansion is the resultant list. If parameter is an array variable
>   subscripted with ‘@’ or ‘*’, the pattern removal operation is applied
>   to each member of the array in turn, and the expansion is the
>   resultant list.

Answer (score 3):

It's called *parameter substitution/expansion*, see [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) for more information.

Your example removes the longest match of `*wlan` from the beginning of the variable `$x`.